# no wlan0 after apt-get upgrade

Tags: networking

As I've mentioned before I've run `apt-get update && upgrade` and my **wlan0** isn't working anymore - please help. The details you've may be asking me:

**uname -a**

```
Linux pi.local 3.6.11+ #538 PREEMPT Fri Aug 30 20:42:08 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04fc:0801 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c315 Logitech, Inc. Classic New Touch Keyboard
```

ifconfig & iwconfig

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:52:db:e1  
          inet addr:192.168.0.182  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8288713 (7.9 MiB)  TX bytes:4455841 (4.2 MiB)
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_multiport            1582  8 
iptable_filter          1493  1 
ip_tables              11490  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               16962  3 ip_tables,xt_multiport,iptable_filter
snd_bcm2835            16432  0 
snd_pcm                77728  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_seq                53482  0 
snd_timer              20110  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device          6462  1 snd_seq
snd                    58744  5 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_seq_device
snd_page_alloc          5169  1 snd_pcm
crc_ccitt               1530  0 
rt2x00usb              11240  0 
rt2x00lib              42342  1 rt2x00usb
mac80211              273979  2 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
cfg80211              184390  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
rfkill                 18298  1 cfg80211
leds_gpio               2243  0 
led_class               3570  2 leds_gpio,rt2x00lib
evdev                   9450  2 
joydev                  9356  0
```

I've already try to reinstall drivers as a last time - this time it didn't help :(

pi@pi / $ **cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp[/quote]
```

and finally 
**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

-

```
#network={
#   ssid="SKYA767C"
#   psk="House!-01"
#   proto=RSN
#   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
#   group=CCMP TKIP
#}

network={
    ssid="SKYA767C"
    psk="House!-01"
    proto=WPA
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=TKIP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Please note that above # are as I've try 1st and 2nd configuration and any of them didn't work. 
What else I need to do?

Can anyone help to fix my wlan0 interface

Comment: What wifi adapter do you use?

Comment: Ralink USB WiFi - details above in lsusb

Comment: please have a look at your `dmesg` output, the kernel probably complains about this on boot, and post it if you find something

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but after running the following command in terminal window.

```
$ sudo rpi-update
```

then do a reboot and all is well.

I am running Raspbian wheezy, after reboot go to desktop and configure your wifi settings with wifi manager.

Comment: This isn't very helpful, as the user needs help getting an internet connection. `rpi-update` requires an internet connection to work.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness they can always use `eth0` to update first

Comment: @PhilVallone True, however, this answer doesn't mention that. I was just pointing out this, as the original question makes no mention of `eth0` just `wlan0`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the default driver for your adapter is not usable. I got this on rtl8188cus (archlinux). I can got the adapter with lsusb and lsmod, but it did not work at all. Complile the driver and insmod should help